# What element raised ng-click in custom directive ng-repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have a repeater inside of a directive that spits out table rows.

When a user clicks on a row I want to highlight that row.

I have something that works, I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing it:

```
.directive('userList', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<table>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<th>User Name</th>'+
                        '<th>First Name</th>'+
                        '<th>Last Name</th>'+
                        '<th>Email Address</th>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user,$event)" ng-mouseenter="overUser($event)" ng-mouseleave="leaveUser($event)">'+
                        '<td ng-click="selectUser(user)">{{user.UserName}}</td>'+
                        '<td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>'+
                        '<td>{{user.LastName}}</td>'+
                        '<td>{{user.Email}}</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</table>',
        scope:{
                selectedUser: '=',
                users: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.selectUser = function(user,event){
                $("div[user-list] tr.ts-li-selected").removeClass("ts-li-selected");
                $(event.target).closest("tr").addClass("ts-li-selected");
                scope.selectedUser=user;
            };
            scope.overUser = function(event){
                $("div[user-list] tr.ts-li-over").removeClass("ts-li-over");
                $(event.target).closest("tr").addClass("ts-li-over");
            };
            scope.leaveUser = function(event){
                $("div[user-list] tr.ts-li-over").removeClass("ts-li-over");
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I've notice `this` doesn't seem to reference the element that raised the event like it would if I'd done it in straight-up java or jQuery.  Rather than that, I've sent the event to my function, event.target always sends the child so I go to the table row to set the class on the row.

I was wondering if there was a...cleaner way of doing this, if there actually was a "this" reference that angular would use in these situations that I could call rather than walking the DOM Tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ng-class` directive to add a special class to the `<tr>` that is clicked on.  Just glancing at your code, it looks like you're setting the `scope.selectedUser` when any `<tr>` is clicked.  So you should be able to do the following:

In your template:

```
...
'<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user)" ng-class="{'ts-li-selected': selectedUser.id == user.id}">'+
    '<td ng-click="selectUser(user)">{{user.UserName}}</td>'+
    '<td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>'+
    '<td>{{user.LastName}}</td>'+
    '<td>{{user.Email}}</td>'+
'</tr>'+
...
```

The `ng-class` will auto apply the `ts-li-selected` class to the `<tr>` whenever the `$scope.selectedUser`'s id matches that row's `user.id`, and will remove the class if that condition is no longer valid.

And then your `$scope.selectUser()` function can be simplified to:

```
scope.selectUser = function(user){
    scope.selectedUser = user;
};
```

Hope that helps.

PS.  As far as your `mouseover` and `mouseleave` classes, can't you just add something like the following to your css stylesheet?

```
tr:hover{ /* special styles here */ }
tr.ts-li-selected:hover{ /* don't do special styles here */ }
```

Comment: That is much slicker! I wish I could give you more plusses.  There's only one fix I had to make with your code: the apostrophes in the ng-class had to be escaped, after that it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/strajk/XAFmb/

You can simlify  to something like this

```
<tr
    ng-repeat="user in users"
    ng-click="selectUser(user)"
    ng-mouseenter="hoverUser(user)"
    ng-class="{
        'ts-li-selected': selectedUser.id == user.id,
        'ts-li-hovered': hoveredUser.id == user.id   
    }"
>
```

and directive to something like this:

```
.directive('userList', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'userList.html' ,
        scope: {
                users: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.selectedUser = null;
            $scope.hoveredUser = null;

            $scope.selectUser = function(user) {
                $scope.selectedUser = user;
            }
            $scope.hoverUser = function(user) {
                $scope.hoveredUser = user;
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: huh, I was wondering if you could reference a url for the template for the directive.  That could make things easier down the line

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 'elem' got the JQuery element on witch the directive is set.

Comment: Not what he's asking.

Comment: the directive is set on a div, that won't give me what I'm looking for.